# How avoid Gunicorn kill the flask connection

Tags: python, http, flask, gunicorn, gevent

I'm running a server with Flask and gunicorn, using gevent workers. One of the endpoints in flask have to upload files to S3, which can take a lot of time.

To make the connection not being killed by gunicorn, I've increase the default timeout, which does not look as a nice implementation.

Is there a way to communicate with gunicorn, while I send the S3 upload, to keep my worker alive?

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, i recommand to use celery